# How do I add a custom error to the gutter in Ace Editor?

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using react-ace to write a custom JS Editor. I want to throw a custom error in the gutter when the user tries to import a module other than ones from a list I specify. How do I go about doing this? I've tried extending a custom mode but this seems to only customize syntax highlighting, I've peaked around ESLint but am not sure if that's the right path. Please help I'm quite lost.

Comment: Do you want to just show a custom error to the user in the gutter space?

Comment: Yes, similar to how syntax errors are treated. I want a red x to appear when "import x" is written and x is not one of the whitelisted modules.

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from the editor, use **getValue**() and then scan the string for the modules you don't want to see and then use the same row and column number and display the error using **setAnnotations**

```
editor.getSession().setAnnotations([{
  row: 1,
  column: 0,
  text: "Error Message", 
  type: "error" //This would give a red x on the gutter
}]);
```

Comment: where do I put this & how do I scan the editor using regex?

Comment: This answer would help you once you scan and want to show. But exactly, you want to scan the list of modules the user has imported? Do you have the list in an array?

Comment: Yes, how do I scan the contents of the editor though? Sorry I'm very new with react-ace. Yeah an example would be ['url', 'zlib', 'crypto'].  And my regex would be: /^import(?!\s+(|\burl\b|\bcrypto\b|\bzlib\b)).*;\s*$/

Comment: I've updated the answer @ryan see if it can help you, and let me know if you need more details